# Cache context drupal don't work

Tags: 8, caching

I changed services.yml file (i use dynamic cache):

```
renderer.config:
required_cache_contexts: ['languages:language_interface', 'theme', 'user.permissions', 'cookies:Drupal.visitor.Country']
```

And sey the cookie properly with an event:

```
$events[KernelEvents::REQUEST][] = ['checkCountry', 30];
...
 user_cookie_save(['Country' => $country]);
```

I checked and the cookie is saved correctly.
But the cache does not work...

Answer (score 2):

Anonymous page cache does not respect cache contexts, I'm guessing that is your problem.

To get that working, you need to switch out the PageCache service in a custom module with a ServiceProvider and override the getCacheId() method.